# How to scale an entire scene in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I have an A-Frame scene:

```
 <a-scene>
      <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
      <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
      <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
      <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
```

How do I scale everything at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap all your entities in a wrapper/parent entity, and then scale that. Position, rotation, and scale of parent entities affect child entities.

```
<a-scene>
  <a-entity scale="2 2 2">
    <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
    <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
    <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
    <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
    <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```